# Setting up R in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, r

I am running QGIS version 3.4.4-Madeira and just installed the R plugin. in Processing->Providers->R I checked the activate box. In the processing toolbox all I see under R is 'test'. The setup tutorial I was following showed additional options in the R drop down in the Processing Toolbox. Are there other steps I need to take to set up R in QGIS?

Comment: Do you see the "R" button in the toolbar of the processing toolbox?

Comment: Yes. When I press it gives the option to "Create New R Script".

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?